# How to create and populate my own ADODB recordset?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I want to create an ADODB recordset with 2 columns - Col1, Col2. Then, I want to put my own data into those two columns. I will not be loading any data from a database. I will manually generate the data to be inserted into ADODB recordset. How do I do this ? I am using C# to do this.

Comment: Don't. Please. Use ADO.Net instead. Then you can just use a System.Net.DataTable

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - Yes, I had seen that in a couple of posts. I have been forced to use ADODB for now. Thats why I am asking only for that.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - Actually, when I see the type of the object, its a System.__ComObject . But, I am told that this System.__ComObject  is actually an ADODB recordset. I am confused.